# Creating vertical line in ggplot with time series data

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, ggplot2

I have data in `tsibble` format that I labelled `tsdb`:

```
A tsibble: 15,000 x 6 [1M]
# Key:       Industry [60]
# Groups:    Industry [60]
   Industry                Period Sales inventory Purchase Sales.diff
   <chr>                    <mth> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1  Apparel manufacturing 2000 Feb  5321     12215     5228         NA
```

I needed to make plots grouped by industry and so I wrote this code for one industry:

```
tsdb %>% 
  filter(Industry == "Manufacturing industries") %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(Sales, inventory, Purchase), names_to = "Series", values_to = "Million_Dollars") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Period, y = Million_Dollars, color = Series)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(vars(Series), scales = "free_y") +
  ggtitle("Manufacturing industries") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

This works fine and I get this plot
[image]

I want to add vertical lines in all the three graphs at select points say "2005 May" and "2008 Jun". To do this, I tried adding:

```
 geom_vline(xintercept = yearmonth("2005 May"), linetype = 4) +
```

and I get this error

```
 Error in UseMethod("rescale") : 
   no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class "c('yearmonth', 'vctrs_vctr')"
```

I even tried:

```
 geom_vline(xintercept = yearmonth(424), linetype = 4) +

 geom_vline(xintercept = scale_x_yearmonth(424), linetype = 4) +

 geom_vline(xintercept = scale_x_yearmonth("2005 May"), linetype = 4) +
```

And I get the error here as:

```
 Error in xj[i] : object of type 'environment' is not subsettable
```

I guess the `yearmonth` needs to be scaled for `ggplot` to understand, but I’m not sure how to do this. I was trying to get one vertical line and then was hoping that I could use `c()` and get all the vertical lines that I need. My objective is to get the vertical lines by specifying the time period, e.g. "2005 May".

Comment: Thanks for that, this is what I did and it worked! geom_vline(xintercept = ymd("2005 May", truncated = 1), linetype = 4) +

Comment: Do you need different vertical lines for different facets?

Comment: Please consider posting this as a comment and/or accepting @IsabellaGhement’s answer.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/284736)

Comment: I used the the answer by Isabella Ghemant as a hint to write and create the answer that would possibly be the best for me, but @KarolisKoncevicius edited my accepted answer into a comment. Wonder why that was done? Wonder why Thomas Bilach is asking me to to post my answer as a comment? Sorry, I don't know the rules and logic of these actions, and am curious to learn.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get what you want is to create a Date variable from your Period variable. The Period only lists the year and month, so you need to add an artificial day of month (e.g., 1) to the year and month to get the date.
Something like this:

```
tsdb$Date <- paste(tsdb$Period, "1")
```

This Date variable is a character variable but you can convert it to a Date variable using the ymd() function in the lubridate package:

```
tsdb$Date <- lubridate::ymd(tsdb$Date)
```

Now you can re-create your plot by replacing x = Period with x = Date in your ggplot. To add your vertical line, just add this layer to your ggplot:

```
geom_vline(xintercept = lubridate::ymd("2005 May 1"), linetype = 4)
```